# relation between Krull dimension of ideal and dimension of solutions to polynomial equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, macaulay2

I would like to solve a system of polynomial equations

to do this in Macaulay2, I wrote it as an ideal, and compute its dimension which is given as $5$.

```
R = CC[sa,sb,sc,sd,se,ca,cb,cc,cd,ce];

I = ideal {-cb*sa - cc*sa + ca*sb + ca*sc, cb*sa - ca*sb - cc*sb + cb*sc, 
 cc*sa + cc*sb - ca*sc - cb*sc, -1 + ca^2 + sa^2, -1 + cb^2 + 
  sb^2, -1 + cc^2 + sc^2}

dim I
```

However, all solutions to this equations are finite isolated points, which contradicts with the dimension of the ideal `dim I = 5`.
[image]

Could anyone help me to solve this confusion? I will appreciate any help to clarify my confusion. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible for a variety to be positive-dimensional but only have finitely many real points: for instance $V(x^2+y^2)$ has only one solution over $\Bbb R$ but is 1-dimensional. This can only occur if the solutions are singular points. What I would guess is happening here is that whatever computer algebra system you used to find the solutions in your image (looks like Mathematica solving for the input angles in your system of sines and cosines) included an assumption of just looking for real points. Can you clarify a little bit about how you got the image?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, I got the image from Mathematica, and restrict to finding real solutions. So ```dim``` tell us the dimension of complex solutions, am I right? if yes, why is that? The field of the coefficients is actually $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @KReiser I may understand it: the solving process is over $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, because of mathematical convenience. The fundamental theorem of algebraic states that the $\mathbb{C}$ field is algebraically closed (every non-constant polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: No, that's not really the whole picture. Solutions of a system of polynomials $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ in variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ over a field $k$ correspond to maximal ideals of $R=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$, and if $k$ is algebraically closed, every such maximal ideal is of the form $(x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n)$ for $a_i\in k$ constants. In particular, if $\dim R>0$, there are infinitely many solutions. If $k$ is not algebraically closed, it may happen that not all maximal ideals are of the form $(x_i-a_i)$, and it may be the case that there are only finitely many solutions over $k$...

Comment: ... but there will always be infinitely many over a suitable algebraic extension of $k$ if $\dim R>0$. I wouldn't say this is about mathematical convenience, it's just about how this stuff works. (Some further results: if $\dim R>0$ but there are only finitely many solutions over $k$, all solutions must be singular points, which you can detect via the Jacobian. This may give you enough ammunition to find all the real solutions, but it's not guaranteed.)